# Looking for sets to use as components of a 1930s - 1940s European city

Tags: sets, clone-brands, design, city, theme

I'm planning to build a 1930s / 1940s European city (like Paris, London, Prague, ...).

As buildings, I'm currently going for modulars that could pass for pre-1950 European buildings, possibly with some customizations.

As cars, I currently have the [Oxford classic car set](https://www.brickmeupscottie.com/products/oxford-bm35219) & the car from [Enlighten's Special Mission Zero set](http://www.enlighten-brick.com/1708.html). In addition, I just bought the [LEGO Shanghai Chase set](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/buildinginstructions/search?initialsearch=7682#?text=7682), the [LEGO Winter Village Station set](https://shop.lego.com/en-US/product/Winter-Village-Station-10259) & [Enlighten's Sunshine Hotel](http://www.enlighten-brick.com/1127.html) for the cars in those sets.

Could anyone of you recommend some specific sets, besides the ones already mentioned, that would be suitable for a 1930 to 1950 city theme and could help me add more detail to my city?

Besides buildings & cars, I'm thinking of details like fountains, statues, benches, kiosks, bus stops & other details that could fit in a European city from between 1930 & 1950 and give it just a bit more character. Also interior details like bedrooms, living rooms or kitchens would be welcome.

As you may have noticed in my choice of cars, I don't care that much about the brand. I'm OK with buying either LEGO or any other brand, as long as the quality is good enough. What's far more important to me than the brand, is that the elements fit into a 1930 to 1950 setting and that they give my city just that little extra...

Answer (score 8):

What about the [75930 Indoraptor Rampage](https://brickset.com/sets/75930-1/Indoraptor-Rampage-at-Lockwood-Estate) for an almost timeless mansion? Without the raptors it is not too expensive.

The [10228 Haunted house](https://brickset.com/sets/10228-1/Haunted-House) could provide a good basis for a rebrick of a nice mansion on the hill just outside of your city. However, this one is ALWAYS expensive, as you probably know.

For many nice little ideas for everyday items and a MOC city, check out [LionBricks' Youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCJvcWOTistqk7sWzzxWSy2A).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Although I'm already aware of both sets you mentioned, I very much appreciate your input. — The 10228 Haunted house is definitely a set I'm considering. I'm not so sure about the 75930 Indoraptor Rampage set, though. It's just the front or a building, really, and even as a front I feel it's a bit lacking in detail. I'd rather go for the [76108 Sanctum Sanctorum Showdown](https://brickset.com/sets/76108-1/Sanctum-Sanctorum-Showdown) instead, which similar in size & price but has a more refined look-and-feel IMO.